# Is sigma-finiteness required?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that f and g are two extended-real valued measurable functions on an arbitrary measure space, such that the integral of g dominates that of f on every set A of the sigma-field. Is it true then, that g dominates f almost everywhere? Is sigma-finiteness of the underlying measure required for this to hold, or does it hold for any measure?

Comment: Consider $A_{n}=\{1< n(f-g)\}$

Comment: What about $f =2$ and $g=1$ on $\{1\}$ where the measure is $\infty$ times the counting measure?